# Return value from a JQuery script in Selenium Webdriver

Tags: javascript, jquery, selenium-webdriver

I have got a problem with obtaining some href's by Selenium Webdriver.
Therefore I have used JQuery script to make it.

```
script = 
"(function() {
    var a = [];
    $("a.class0.class1.link").each(function() {
        a.push($(this).attr('href'));
    });
    return a;
})()";
```

executed by such code:

`result = javascriptExecutor.executeScript(script)`

But result has null value.
When I run that script in Chrome console I have got correct result - array of href's. What I did wrongly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I have solved problem.
There are 2 ways of achieving result - obtaining href's from links.

```
script = "return $('a.class0.class1.link');"
```

execute such script and get an Array of WebElements from which it is possible to get attributes:

```
val js = browser.asInstanceOf[JavascriptExecutor]
val scriptResult = js.executeScript(script)
val result = ListBuffer.empty[String]

scriptResult.asInstanceOf[util.ArrayList[WebElement]].forEach(x => result +=
  x.getAttribute("href"))

result.toList
```

or in second way - execute such JQuery code:

```
val script = "return (function() {var table = [];$('a.class0.class1.link').each(function() { table.push($(this).attr('href'));});return table;})();"
```

and collect result:

```
val js = browser.asInstanceOf[JavascriptExecutor]
val scriptResult = js.executeScript(javascript)
scriptResult.asInstanceOf[util.ArrayList[String]].asScala.toList
```

Comment: Don't forget to come back and mark this answer as accepted so the question doesn't get left unanswered.